# Cheapest way to send small strings of data (30~40 bytes) over the internet?

Tags: c#, sockets

I need to send small strings o data every minute or so from 100 or so android cellphones to some kind of server. The problem is that each MB i use is around 1.5 dollars, so the cost scales greatly if the data size is too big.

I have tried using post, but it used 400 bytes of data per string sent. I have tried to make a C# socket server where a client connects, sends the data and disconnects, but it still used 400 bytes of data, perhaps a bit more...how is this possible? Could netbalancer be measuring it wrong? I used client.Send("string") in c#.

Will it be any different if i do it from a mobile data cellphone? Im doing it to another laptop in a LAN.

I have also tried ftp and it was too bloated too.

I need the network consumption of each string sent be around 100-120 bytes or so, is this even possible? What tools could i use?
---Update---

Here is the C# client code (will be Java if I find out how to optimize the size)

```
            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
        Int32 port = 10000;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0001#37.12489#-106.35871");   
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.15.16", port);

        int bytesSent = client.Client.Send(bytes);

        client.Close();
```

Here is the PHP socket running on XAMPP. I could make it in any language, as I am probably going to have to use it as a relay to a server that doesn't allow sockets.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);
/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
* as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false)
{
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) 
{
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) 
{
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do 
{
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) 
    {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }

    $buf = socket_read($msgsock,50);
    socket_close($msgsock);

    echo "$buf\n";
} while (true);
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Comment: I never heard of it before, im only reading about it now. Can you connect it to an android proccess or service like some kind of pipe? I will have full access to the phones and no one else willl use them.

Comment: If the size of the data is the same it will be the size of the data that is the problem. Can you show us some data examples? Posting will be sending field names as well as field data and sockets is all well and good but how are you serializing the data before you send it? Sometimes a positional format is the way to go i.e. for a stream representing name|candy|meat you'd send harry|fudge|pork so you don't send field names you instead just assume a given format/protocol. On top of that compression may further reduce your payload size... or actually even increase it depending on the data.

Comment: I agree with rism; if you have full control over the entire process, you can simply assume proper formatting and send as little data as possible. For example, is it absolutely necessary it be a string?
May not be entirely what you're after, but, here's a search for C# efficient socket:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+efficient+socket
It might give you some ideas.

Comment: Why every minute? The,data will start to add up for your consumers eventually. May take a while, but bytes add up

Comment: As far as I know, .net uses Unicode strings by default. So that's a x2 bytes just from that, alone.

Comment: There's also the TCP/IP handshake and IP overheads to take into account.

Comment: Does your requierement of max 120bytes per messages include the traffic in both directions (*in* and *out*) or for *out* only?

Comment: Can you afford loss of messages?

Comment: Would you be in the need to establish a new connection for each message, or may it be possible to re-use an existing connection?

Comment: `client.Send("string")` isn't a valid way to use a `Socket` instance, so right there you're not sharing enough information to understand your scenario. Every network protocol has some overhead just for each bit of transmitted data, and even more every time you are creating and shutting down TCP connections. The most efficient use of data will be when you minimize that overhead. You can obviously reduce costs simply by reducing frequency of transmission. That said, 400 bytes per minute comes to 0.5 MB/day; $1.50/MB is crazy expensive, but is still only 75c/device/day in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for all the sugggestions, im going to try to answer them 1 by 1.

Comment: srim and sine - The data im sending is just an id, a latitude and longitude like: 0001#30.71234#-106.45631

Comment: Why send that as a string instead of simply packing this into int float float? You're controlling both ends you don't need a separator, just send the data as you need it and read it back on the other end, definately don't put it into a string. 30.71234 is 8 characters, each of them larger than the float and for a less precise result. Just add int / float/ float directly to your Stream and read that back on the other hand. If you can afford data loss go with UDP too. Also 1.5$/mb sounds massively prohibitive, what are you paying that for?

Comment: I could optimize it a bit more to remove 3-5 characters, but i don't think it would shrink it so much.

Daryl- I wanted it to have some precision, but if there is no other way i would lower the rate.

Alk- 120 bytes overall...i can afford loss of packages, but i can't afford losing them too many times in a row, say up to 5 times (5 minutes). 
If i could send a byte back to confirm and resend if necessary it would be great, but not if its too costly.

I don't need to establish a new one, I just found out about connectionless sockets,  maybe that would help?

Comment: Peter- What do you mean its invalid : |? It does work, but I saw other ways and I don’t know if this one is the best. I just added the code. Would maintaining a connection somehow or sending it trough udp help? 
I can reduce the frequency, but  I wanted that to be my last resort. Perhaps it wouldn’t be that bad tho. 
Yeah its crazy expensive, maybe individual ones not so much but the main problem is that there will be 80-110 cell phones sending their locations all the time, so it will escalate quickly.

Comment: Ronan - So you mean it's possible to send the float itself and not the string? Would simply sending it in a float data type accomplish this? Im gonna try it right now :D

Yeah the cellphone company sucks here, their fees are designed to make people pay as much as possible. This is mobile data, and they try to make it so people have to pay as often and costly as possible. I have not found a nother company or something, they have a country-wide monopoly.

Comment: Im also going to try udp and see how it goes, thanks.

Could TCP be using so muhch data to establish the connection as some people mentioned here?

Maybe dumb question but If I send it like int, int float how can i bind the 3 of them as coming from a single source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do not send character strings, send binary data (preferable in network-byte-order). Sending the info in binary format reduces the size of the pay-load.
- Go for a UDP connection, as this reduces protocol overhead.
- Invent a minimal protocol to detect packet loss and allow requering of packets.

  An idea:

  Add a serial number to each packet. Keep a minimum number of packets sent on the sender side. Allow the sender to receive answers from the receiver. Let the receiver send a request to have the sender resend any serial number missing.

  This would allow to fill gaps, which were introduced during a time window defined by the amount of packets kept by the sender.

  For the serial number one addtional byte per packet might do, two bytes most certainly will be enough. However the maximum serial number (and with this its size) depends on the maxium number of packets the sender holds as history to be able to resend them.